# Почему метод POST не определяет нажатие кнопки

Tags: php, form, button, submit

Есть форма типа:

```
<form method="POST" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
    <input class="full-width has-padding" id="auth"  type="submit"  value="Create account">
    </p>
</form>
```

Исходя из данного кода:

```
<?if(isset($_POST['auth']))
    { echo 'Yes'; } else { echo 'No';}
?>
```

**Кнопка с идентификатором auth, при клике, должна вывести значение: Yes**, но это не так, почему? и как исправить?

Форма регистрации/авторизации взята отсюда: https://codyhouse.co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/

Answer (score 2):

Вы проверяете переменную **[auth]**, но она при этом с формы не передается. 
Укажите **name**, для **input**

**UPDATE**

```
<form method = "POST" action = "reg.php">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "auth" value = "VALUE">
   <input type = "submit" value = "Create">
</form>
```

Comment: Я указал, все-равно выводит значение: **No** `<input class="full-width has-padding" name="auth"  type="submit"  value="Create account">` А если я создаю именно через `<button name="auth">Submit<button>` то POST запрос обрабатывается

Comment: @ВасилийГилберт, смотри добавил в свой пост небольшой пример как должна выглядеть форма, в моем случает при нажатие на инпут отправки, файл reg.php получается переменную POST[auth], которая имеет значение ''Value'

Comment: если я не укажу класс, то все стили пропадают. А так годно, но не совсем то, что мне нужно:)

Comment: @ВасилийГилберт, да класс можно указать без проблем, я как маленький пример просто накинул. В данном ключе классы на функциональность никоим образом не влияют

Answer (score 1):

1. поле action можно оставить пустым, файл сам себя и выполнит.
2. $_POST['auth'] обращается к аттрибуту name а не id.

Comment: Я указал, все-равно выводит значение: **No** `<input class="full-width has-padding" name="auth"  type="submit"  value="Create account">` А если я создаю именно через `<button name="auth">Submit<button>` то POST запрос обрабатывается